# Problema de Acentuação ao consumir WebService no Windows Server

Tags: java, web-service, codificação-de-caracteres, restful

> Correção

Estou com um problema de acentuação ao consumir WebService no Windows Server.
Tenho apache-tomcat-7.0.63 instalado no windows server 2008, e como SGB, o PostGres 9.4 e com o Java 8.
O erro acontece quando executo fora do NetBeans. Ou seja, se executo fora em qualquer ambiente ele grava os caracteres errados, mas se executo dentro do NetBeans(Depurando ou apenas Executando) ele grava os caracteres normais.

[image: imagem do erro]

código do web service

```
@POST
@Path("cliente/sincronizar")
@Consumes("application/json;charset=utf-8")
public Response createClienteInJSON(String param) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ContaCTR contaCTR = new ContaCTR();

    ParamCliente paramCliente = gson.fromJson(param, ParamCliente.class);

    Conta conta = contaCTR.carregar(paramCliente.getToken());

    if (!paramCliente.getClientes().isEmpty() && conta != null) {
        try {
            WsAuxiliar.sincronizarCliente(paramCliente.getClientes(), conta);

            ClienteCTR clienteCTR = new ClienteCTR();
            List<Cliente> clientes = clienteCTR.listar(conta.getContaid(), "codigointerno");
            WsAuxiliar.sincronizarEmail(paramCliente.getEmails(), conta, clientes);
            WsAuxiliar.sincronizarEndereco(paramCliente.getEnderecos(), conta, clientes);
            WsAuxiliar.sincronizarTelefone(paramCliente.getTelefones(), conta, clientes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Falha ao sincronizar Cliente. Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return Response.status(201).build();
}
```

código cliente consumindo web service

```
    public Retorno sendPostClientes(String token) throws Exception {
    try {
        ParamCliente paramCliente = new ParamCliente();
        paramCliente.carregar();
        paramCliente.setToken(token );

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String input = gson.toJson(paramCliente);

        URL url = new URL(Configuracao.carregar().getWebserv() + "cliente/sincronizar");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");            

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Retorno.criarRetorno(Boolean.TRUE, "Erro ao sincronizar clientes!\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return Retorno.criarRetorno(Boolean.FALSE, "Clientes Sincronizado com sucesso!");
}
```

Configuração da base de dados Postgres

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já um muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Alguém teria uma dica?

Comment: Já olhou as configurações do postgree?

Comment: Peço até desculpa, pois o erro acontece quando executo fora do NetBeans. Ou seja, se executo fora em qualquer ambiente ele vai com os caracteres errados, mas se executo dentro do NetBeans(Depurando ou apenas Executando) ele manda os caracteres normais. 
E eu ainda não tenho solução para este erro...

Comment: Sim, mas a sua tabela no postgree está UTF-8 ?

Comment: Sim ele esta UTF-8, coloquei acima, uma imagem com as configurações do banco.

Comment: Estou pensando no que possa ser.

Comment: Tenta usar `ISO-8859-1` e ve o que da

Comment: Com o ISO-8859-1 funcionou perfeitamente executando fora do NetBeans mas dentro (Depurando ou simplesmente Executando) parou de funcionar.
Coisa de louco...Coisa de Programador...kkkk

Comment: Estranho... Alguma coisa está passando despercebida, rs

Comment: Talvez o NetBeans esteja configurado como UTF-8

Comment: Vou deixa ISO-8859-1 pois é mais importante funcionar no executável separado de que no NetBeans. Então posso dizer que resolvi parcialmente. Muito Obrigado  Techies. Que Deus lhe recompense.

Comment: Por nada, Já que resolveu parcialmente espere um pouco e veja se outra pessoa responda com uma solução melhor, caso ano aconteça não se esqueça de colocar como resolveu seu problema, dessa forma poderá ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo você pode postar sua solução do problema como resposta abaixo e marcar como aceita. O site funciona diferente de foruns.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Response createClienteInJSON(String param) {
...
}
```

Espero que funcione

Comment: Mas ele já não está fazendo isso?

Comment: Peço até desculpa, pois o erro acontece quando executo fora do NetBeans. Ou seja, se executo fora em qualquer ambiente ele vai com os caracteres errados, mas se executo dentro do NetBeans(Depurando ou apenas Executando) ele manda os caracteres normais. 
E eu ainda não tenho solução para este erro...

Comment: @Techies pelo código postado não, o que tem o *charset* lá é o `@Consumes`. Provavelmente o erro é ao produzir a resposta mesmo. @JoãoPaulo conseguiu resolver só configurando o `@Produces`?

Comment: Na verdade testei da forma que me passou também mas deu o mesmo erro. Mudando o charset inverti o local do erro rsrs... antes funcionava dentro do netbeans e externo não, agora funciona externo mas dentro do NB parou de funcionar... Mas como o executável externo é mais importante, afirmo que consegui contornar o erro. Muito obrigado @BrunoCésar e desculpe a demora no retorno, mas o feriado foi longe da civilização..